# Real time prediction system with R

Tags: r, regression, prediction, real-time

I am trying to build a real-time prediction system for my application. I am yet to actually build any system involving R.

I have some data on MySQL which I'm using to train the model, and I want to build a linear regression model with R.

How should I go about it?

What are the info that I would need to start?

Comment: Have you looked at the lm function in the stats package? That is a standard function that fits a linear regression. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lm.html